# How do I align input form buttons in HTML

Tags: css

I have used the vertical align rule in css, but the last buttons of the operations in the calculator is not alinged properly and it looks bad.

What could be the problem?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Tsdz9ha.jpg]

```
.value {
height:80;
width:80;
font-size:30px;
color:black;
vertical-align: middle;
}
#ans {
height:60;
width:335;
}
.reset {
height:80;
width:80;
font-size:25px;
color:black;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Well, where's your HTML?

Comment: You need to add your html also,

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: add your html code

Comment: put your buttons in a div tag and then give property display:inline-block;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The html is here [link](http://i.imgur.com/3bjvUli.jpg)

Comment: I have also have it in a jsfiddle but there the results are not proper https://jsfiddle.net/cq4qcrbf/

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code which aligned properly,i am not sure about your html.

```css
.value {
height:80px;
width:80px;
font-size:30px;
color:black;
vertical-align: middle;
}
ul{
  width:400px;
  background:black;
  }
li{
display:inline-block;
list-style:none;
background:gray;
border-bottom:1px solid black;  

}
.reset {
height:80px;
width:80px;
font-size:25px;
color:black;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="value">7</li> 
 <li class="value">8</li> 
 <li class="value">9</li> 
 <li class="value">0</li> 
 <li class="value">4</li> 
 <li class="value">5</li> 
 <li class="value">6</li> 
 <li class="reset">Reset</li>  
 <li class="value">1</li> 
 <li class="value">2</li> 
 <li class="value">3</li> 
 <li class="value">=</li>
 <li class="value">+</li> 
 <li class="value">-</li> 
 <li class="value">*</li> 
 <li class="value">/</li>
 <ul>
```

Comment: Shijn you have created a list not a calculator i  want my buttons to look exactly like in your snippet. I have also added my html the link is in above comments

Comment: @AhmedAli I am not here working for you.we are just trying to help others.In your question,You mention the last row is not aligned  thats why i created the list.You are not provide any html